# Touchpad going crazy. Cursor don't move and auto clicking!

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I'm working on my laptop, and sometimes, the touchpad going crazy, it's doesn't move and auto clicking. It's only happen in ubuntu, not in Windows. I don't know why

I have a Acer Aspire E 15, Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: please update here, if found solution. I am using Ubuntu 18 on Lenovo machine, suddenly it started behaving like you explained.